# Is it possible to work remotely for a US company without a German legal entity from Germany?

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card

My fiancé recently accepted a job at a large US tech company for a Munich-based team. The company is handling his immigration paper work and he'll receive a blue card. I believe, based on what I've read, that as his spouse, I'll be eligible for a work permit in Germany. We're getting married in July and will move in August.

I currently work remotely for a medium-sized US tech company as well with no German presence and I would like to continue to work for them remotely from Germany. I've done a bit of research and it seems like this would be possible with a Blue Card, provided that my US company follows German employment law.

**Is it possible to work for an American company remotely from Germany if that American company does not have a German legal entity as long as the American company can follow German employment law?** If so, how do I go about applying for the Blue Card under these circumstances?

Comment: " as long as the American company can follow German employment law" this can't happen, US companies can't employ someone following German laws.